# BIM360 Forge API topFolders end point

Tags: autodesk-forge, endpoint, autodesk-bim360

When I call the topFolders endpoint with an admin users all works well.
However when i call it with normal user that do have have access the "Project Files" folder but have access to subsequent folders, I get 10 folders in the data ("Project Files", "ProjectTB", and some hex named folders) but not the one I provided access to the user.

Any assistance is highly appreciated

Comment: Are u using the same scopes and authentication for both requests ?. The hex and projectTb folders usually show when using a 2legged token.

Comment: You were right i was using a 2legged authentication, when i moved to 3 legged all worked well

Comment: Good to hear. glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

For the topFolder to get you only the folders you have access to you need to use 3 legged Authentication. 
if you get projectTB or any hex named folders this mean you used 2 legged Authentication